# XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net-2010

I have created a CORS request from my .aspx page.
My Ajax request as follows.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "https://api.kraken.io/v1/url",
    data: JSON.stringify('{"auth": {"api_key:"' + api_key + '","api_secret:"' + API_Secret + '"},"url:"+ "http://test.pw.com/ScreenShots/3C65B6.jpg","callback_url:"+ "http://test4.pw.com/Admin/TaskAndProjectSearch.aspx","json": true}'),
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result.d);
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {

    }
});
```

I am using IIS8 and I have enabled CORS by adding following to web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Access" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Still I got the following error .
XMLHttpRequest cannot load url. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 .
Have anyone got any idea about this.I need this to be fixed as soon as possible.
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @BhanuChowdary you need to send additional data too.

Comment: So you control the headers for api.kraken.io?

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this same error just a few minutes ago.  Turns out the URL my api was posting to was wrong.  When I fixed that, everything worked fine.  Make sure your URL is correct.

Answer (score -1):

You have uncorrect web.config content. You should close the `<httpProtocol>` tag before `</system.webServer>`. Without that, your application won't even start...

Comment: I believe this is the answer to the question. I tell OP what to do, and why to do it. Some answers don't have long explanations and examples, they're just answers :)